# Area 51 commitment message used for spam

Tags: discussion, area-51, spam

Perhaps the proposer of [Politics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics) won't thank me for this, but ...

[This user](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/70756/umesh-sharma)'s commitment message for the site is obviously an attempt at comment spam:

> "Good article, If you need any law related query, please visit www.legalhelplineindia.com"

... which I have to admit made me laugh when I saw it - but I get the feeling they might not be quite as committed to the proposal as they claim.

I don't see any way to flag either the commitment or the user - is this the right place to bring it up?

Comment: You could also post it on http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/ with the [`area51-meta` tag](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51-meta), I believe.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Come out from under that bridge, I dare you...

Comment: @sixlettervariables. It's not legit. "Good article" posted on something that's not an article is a definite sign of a spambot. I've reported this in [The Assembly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7030451#7030451).

Comment: @TRiG: You have been trolled, [billygoat gruff](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/seems-legit-sounds-legit). :-P

Comment: It's on the [19th page of commitments](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906?page=19), in case anyone's wondering.  I didn't see a way to get there directly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Or the first if you sort by 'most recent'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, this is the right place.

This user and its commitment have been destroyed.