# Should we answer the question being asked, or be as helpful as possible?

Tags: discussion, answers, design, philosophy

So I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627972/using-arrays-from-a-different-class) and there are two answers there that I like

- jlordo's answer succinctly and clearly **answers the question that is being asked**
- RobHruska's answer doesn't exactly answer the question that is being asked, but, rather, answers the **real question that a new programmer would be asking if they knew how to ask it**

So I guess what I'm saying is, is it preferable in the StackExchange paradigm to *answer what the question asker is saying exactly* or to *be as helpful as possible, to teach what the questioner really needs to learn*.

Comment: Rob Hruska's answer actually did appear to succinctly answer the question.

Comment: @SamIam: In the original question, qwertyRocker was trying to do a static assignment to a class and it wouldn't compile because the variable wasn't assigned statically. jlordo said "use `static`". RobHruska said "you probably want to make a new instance of the class instead". Don't get me wrong, I like both answers actually (and I upvoted RobHruska's answer), but it's not the verbatim answer to qwertyRocker's question.

Comment: [Old Shoe Or Glass Bottle?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122318/151211)

Comment: @AakashM: I want to give this question's checkmark to that post, haha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is preferable to help the question asker as best you can.

If that means reading between the lines and suggesting a different approach, then please do so! If you can address both the original question *and* teach the asker about better methods, so much the better. You have helped the question asker just that little bit more.

In your specific example, the answer that addressed what you call the *real* question, was awarded the 'helpful answer' flag; the question asker felt that answer helped him most. And that's the whole point of Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1, but avoid non sequitur answers.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: how about non sequitur comments? :-P

Comment: *"reading between the lines and suggesting a different approach"* sometimes ends up with answers like, "properly formatted code and following appropriate design patterns can help with your problem". Or "Unrelated Common Problem X may be affecting your application and here is a solution to it." While yes, they are both "answers" in a loose sense and meet the OP's test of "helpful as possible", they are not encouraged. (I like giraffes)

Comment: Okay, first had to test if this was another ['seems legit'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156878/area-51-commitment-message-used-for-spam#comment452118_156878) comment. :-)  Agreed, non sequitur answers are never helpful, don't use them to pad out your post.

Answer (score 2):

Being helpful is good, but remember that the purpose is to make a resource for future visitors as well, not just to help the asker.

Even if there may be a much better solution for the asker's specific problem, there may be future visitors who are looking for *exactly* what was requested. (Or, more annoyingly, future questions may be closed as a duplicate of the question that was literally asked, even if the answers aren't applicable because nobody answered the literal question.) For their sake, we should try to make sure that there is *at least* one answer that addresses the question that was asked.

If somebody else has already posted such an answer, then you can just post an alternative. If not, then even if you're suggesting an alternative you should try to also address the literal question in your answer.

Comment: If I could summarize your answer into one sentence, it would be "do both". Is that about right? This kind of thing comes up more with the questions like "I am a beginner, HELP!" than "I have this very specific problem with Spring and Hibernate blah blah"

Comment: @durron597 Yup, the ideal is to do both, if practical.